# Send command to running process

Tags: java, process

is it possible to send a command to an running Process like in the example below?
And how would you do that?

```
Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

For processes that read and write to the command line use `p.getOutputStream()` to send data to the process and `p.getIntputStream()` to read data from the process. For GUI processes you need native code to send messages depending on the operating system.

**Edit:**
Example code for processes that are reading/writing to the console:

```java
Process process = pb.start();

// process stdout
Scanner stdout =  new Scanner(
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getOutputStream())));

// process stdin
PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(
    new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(process.getInputStream())), true);

// sending commands to the process
stdin.println("command1");
stdin.println("command2");
stdin.println("command3");

// reading process output
while (stdout.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("Process output: " + stdout.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: And how can i do that :/? Already tried something but in.transferTo(out); say that the method is unknown for the type of Inputstream...https://paste.ggc-project.de/?b1684d70b2ca5a6a#9H1wQUtnv3VdjmkZBhi1oyqsJTvkVPPDkejXwV6fzBjm

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly not what you are wanting to achieve, but yes, you can communicate to a running Process with Process.getOutputStream()